# Rails Partials - can't perform a collect on a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I'm trying to render a partial, and want to use symbols to pass in the data:

```
<%= render 'form', :locals => { :course => @course, :categories => @categories } %>
```

In my partial though, I can't perform a collect on the :categories symbol, I get this error:

```
    undefined method `collect' for :categories:Symbol

    Extracted source (around line #9):

<%= f.select :category_id, :categories.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}, {}, :style => 'font-size:1em;width:250px;'  %>
```

Can you not use symbols this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `collect` on `:categories`, instead of `categories`.

```
<%= f.select :category_id, categories.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id]}, {}, :style => 'font-size:1em;width:250px;'  %>
```

instead of

```
<%= f.select :category_id, :categories.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}, {}, :style => 'font-size:1em;width:250px;'  %>
```

Moreover, you are mixing the two syntax to call `render`. It should be either

```
<%= render partial: 'form', :locals => { :course => @course, :categories => @categories } %>
```

or

```
<%= render 'form', :course => @course, :categories => @categories %>
```

Comment: Yes it works if I do it that way, but I'm trying to follow best practices here. Oh the irony :)

Comment: The best practice is to pass the variable as a local, as you did, and the way you fetch it inside the partial is by using the auto-generated reference called in the same way of the local, but of course without the `:` that represents the way to write a symbol.

Comment: There was another error with the way you call `render` and you pass the `locals`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks - just so I fully understand this, why do I need to put in "render partial" in there? I thought you didn't need the word partial anymore?

Comment: It depends. You can omit it, but then the hash of attributes will be treated as `:locals`. `render` accepts multiple options, rendering a partial or view is just the default. Here's why you still have the option to pass `:partial`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reference the symbols in your partial, reference the instance of them.

```
<%= f.select :category_id, categories.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}, {}, :style => 'font-size:1em;width:250px;'  %>
```

Comment: The I get this error: undefined local variable or method `categories' for #<#<Class:0x007ffa360021b0>:0x007ffa2bec9ed8>  it works if I plop @categories in there so it's not an issue with the data.